# React.js Bind results as cards which are getting from web api

Tags: reactjs

Hi all I have a working sample when I use the data as constant in React js. The same output I need when the data is returning from a controller can some one help me. Here is the expected on https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KQVmzK

My code with controller call, in render I would like to render the result as in the sample

```
class UserList extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { person: [] };
    }

componentDidMount() {
    this.UserList();
}

UserList() {
    fetch("/ReactJS/GetMessage")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(
        (result) => {
            alert(result);
            this.setState({
                //isLoaded: true,
                person: result

            });
        }
        )
}

render() {
    // need to bind the html result as per in the fiddle
}
}
ReactDOM.render(<UserList />, document.getElementById('form'));
```

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing

Comment: Nothing I just want to bind the result which is returning from MVC controller in the same way that us getting displayed in fiddle

Answer (score 0):

```js
render(){
  {this.state.person.length > 0 
    ? 
    <CardLists cards={this.state.person}>
    :
    null
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: is it an answer or comment? I am not bothered about warning now what I need is output as expected

Comment: But how can I apply this in my render, I am using `UserList` will this works with the above code which I have written

Comment: from your codepen, it seems like it is working for you now? is that what you need?

Comment: My issue is the one in codepen works fine but I would like to achieve the same with the code that I pasted here

Comment: `render() {
    // need to bind the html result as per in the fiddle
}` Here I need the logic

Answer (score 0):

Finally after lot of research I did myself

```
class Application extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            camperArr: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.callApi("/ReactJS/GetMessage");
    }

    callApi(str) {
        var req = str;
        this.serverRequest = $.get(req, function (result) {
            result.map(function (elem, idx) {
                elem["id"] = idx + 1;
            });
            this.setState({
                camperArr: result
            });
        }.bind(this));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <CardList list={this.state.camperArr} />
        );
    }
}

// the list of campers
class CardList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        var list = this.props.list;
        return (
            <div>
                {list.map((card, index) => <Card key={index} {...card} />)}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
class Card extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{ margin: 'lem' }}>
                <img width="75" src={this.props.UserImage} />
                <div style={{ display: 'inline-block', marginLeft: 10 }}>
                    <div style={{ fontSize: '1.25em', fontWeight: 'bold' }} >{this.props.UserName}</div>
                    <div>{this.props.Company}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('form'));
```